# should i put this code in the model or controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, model

ok so I am upping my Laravel and MVC skills..currently all this in the controller (i know its bad thats why I am here I am trying to do it better :D)

Receive Data from UI as post (Done)
I have to store a file (Done)
store that file ID and path in a Files Table (Done)
Create new record and use the above record ID using query builder(Done)

but should I keep this in the controller or does this belong in the model specificlaly getting the files and storing the record etc.

do i build it the long way in the controller and use save()? 
or return from a new model for files and pass that through on return (this i feel is best way ).

> FileModel (To be built)
>
> saves files returns file ID from file table
>
> Business Model saves buisness data
>
> controllerfile:
>   use /app/fileModel
>
> $fileStored = call file model and passes request->file
>   for storing
>
> $businessFile = $fileStored;
>
> Save()

I think I have answered my own question but I am just making sure.

I am known for coding in anti patterns so I am asking for a bit of guidance not code thank you

Also if anyone knows of a place to just discuss laravel stuff so not to put here I would love a a good conversation, some my questions may seem stupid, I just need a soundboard at times.

Comment: Common practice is to use a ViewModel. If you are using MVC then you already have a Model. Build on the that in a view model to get everything you need. You are still going to have to have a save in the controller, unless you use a stored procedure to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

ok so this works and is my solution.

```
   public function create(Request $request)
    {

//get files from request
        $Match1 = $request->file('Match1')->store('media/scores');
        $Match2 = $request->file('Match2')->store('media/scores');
        $Match3 = $request->file('Match3')->store('media/scores');
//build collection array to loop through saving them 
        $collection = collect([$Match1,$Match2,$Match3]);
// store return paths in to new array
        $mediapaths = array();
//loop through collections saving details in to files table pushing to the paths array
        foreach($collection as $MatchScore) {
          $ScoresSaved = Files::create([
            'user_id' => $request->userID,
             'file_name' => $request->title,
             'type' => 'png',
             'category_id'=>3,
             'path' => $MatchScore,
             'is_public'=>0
         ]);
        array_push($mediapaths, $ScoresSaved);
       }

//Save the score with new media path to the model
       $scores = new Scores;
       $scores->tournament=22; 
       $scores->round='Finals'; 
       $scores->homeArcade=2578; 
       $scores->homePlayer=2; 
       $scores->opponenet=2; 
       $scores->Match1=$mediapaths[0]['id'];
       $scores->Match2=$mediapaths[1]['id']; 
       $scores->Match3=$mediapaths[2]['id']; 
       $scores->Match1Score=22; 
       $scores->Match2Score=44; 
       $scores->Match3Score=88; 
       $scores->comments='testing full flow'; 
       $scores->winner=2; 
       $scores->referee=3; 
       $scores->confirmed=1; 
       $scores->dispute=0; 
       $scores->submitedBy=2;
       $scores->save();

       return response()->json([
        'result' => 'Success'
    ]);

   }
```